# Stack Exchange ping pong and pool rooms

Tags: discussion, fun, company, stack-exchange-team

So I was creepin around the site and I saw two interesting pictures that I have questions about. http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange

1. Which current SE employee is the best at ping pong?
2. Do you guys ever hold ping pong tournaments? Singles/Doubles?
3. It seems that the room is pretty long, however it seems there is limited width. So has anyone ever ran into the wall trying to save a shot? Or does it not get that competitive ever?

   [image]
4. Which current SE employee is the best at pool?
5. Do you guys ever hold pool tournaments? Singles/Doubles?

   [image]

Comment: Upvoted.. interesting question.

Comment: @LowerClassOverflowian I don't think that comment is helping your case for up votes. Anyway, up voted, I like it

Comment: The amount of time you spend composing a question doesn't guarantee that your question is good, or that it will be well-received by the community.  In any event, the [always-friday-in-iceland] tag was banned a long time ago, and you're three days early anyway.  [We is serious cats here](http://stokereport.com/files/serious-cat.jpg).

Comment: upvoted also, interesting question and always good to get to know the SE people

Comment: "I had to say something to show the pure bias some people have in their voting habits." - it's not particularly clear a) what bias you're talking about b) in what way you've shown it

Comment: -1 to the unicorn question, good point.

Comment: If you think those pictures are interesting, then you have some exploring to do: [upstairs](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Stack+Exchange/@40.708659,-74.006579,3a,75y,142.12h,86.03t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sd8njc0EiDMgAAAQIt-NMmA!2e0!3e2!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0xf9742bc540e39399), [downstairs](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Stack+Exchange/@40.708464,-74.006616,3a,75y,15.51h,72.34t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sDu6WHJ5-nGMAAAQIt-PpTg!2e0!3e2).

Comment: (And [this other footage of the ping pong](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.70872,-74.007011,3a,75y,166.6h,74.39t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1sIO26x8bfllEAAAQIt-NLPQ!2e0!3e2).)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Disclaimer: I'm a remote employee so I'm not in the NY office a lot.

1. Not sure who the best is. Jarrod, Matt Sherman, and Jay Hanlon are all pretty good.
2. The last team summit we held a doubles ping-pong tournament.
3. Not sure about how aggressive people get. When I've played, people take it easy in general.

The pool table is from the London office I believe. There's no pool table in the NYC office.

Comment: Who needs a pool table [when Mario is in the bathroom](https://www.google.com/maps/@40.7085,-74.006952,3a,75y,67.53h,42.99t/data=!3m5!1e1!3m3!1s-1kn9ljqM3QAAAQIt-PpQg!2e0!3e2)!